# Has register_post_type() changed for WordPress 4.0

Tags: custom-post-types

I know it's easy to blame the system update rather than user error, but I thought I would double check if anyone else has been running into the same issue!

The following register_post_type() has worked through several updates, but very recently on a 4.0 update the custom post type has "disappeared" from the wp-admin sidebar menu, and also doesn't render on the site.

Do I need to update the following in any way?

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'rsf_properties',
            array(
                    'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Properties' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'properties' )
                    ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 2,
            'rewrite' => false,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Comment: Your code works for me on 4.0. Perhaps you have a plugin or theme conflict. http://cl.ly/image/2d3j231W3E17

Comment: What happens if something else already occupies menu position 2? In that situation your menu item would be overridden, and it would vanish.

Comment: That's incorrect. A second post type or menu item with the same menu position won't overwrite anything, the menus will simply fall in sequence if they share a menu position.

Comment: I've has issues with register_post_type in WordPress 4, take a good look and see that your declarations follow all the function's arguments: (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

My $post_type was more than 20 characters, hence didn't even registered.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question literally — no, there had been no major code changes to `register_post_type()` between 3.9 and 4.0.

This is the diff for the changes (from `git diff origin/3.9 -- src/wp-includes/post.php`):

```
 function register_post_type( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
    global $wp_post_types, $wp_rewrite, $wp;
@@ -1235,8 +1333,10 @@ function register_post_type( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
    $post_type = sanitize_key( $post_type );
    $args->name = $post_type;

-   if ( strlen( $post_type ) > 20 )
+   if ( strlen( $post_type ) > 20 ) {
+       _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Post types cannot exceed 20 characters in length' ), '4.0' );
        return new WP_Error( 'post_type_too_long', __( 'Post types cannot exceed 20 characters in length' ) );
+   }

    // If not set, default to the setting for public.
    if ( null === $args->publicly_queryable )
@@ -1262,7 +1362,7 @@ function register_post_type( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
    if ( null === $args->exclude_from_search )
        $args->exclude_from_search = !$args->public;

-   // Back compat with quirky handling in version 3.0. #14122
+   // Back compat with quirky handling in version 3.0. #14122.
    if ( empty( $args->capabilities ) && null === $args->map_meta_cap && in_array( $args->capability_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
        $args->map_meta_cap = true;

@@ -1337,6 +1437,7 @@ function register_post_type( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
        add_permastruct( $post_type, "{$args->rewrite['slug']}/%$post_type%", $permastruct_args );
    }

+   // Register the post type meta box if a custom callback was specified.
    if ( $args->register_meta_box_cb )
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $args->register_meta_box_cb, 10, 1 );

@@ -1357,7 +1458,7 @@ function register_post_type( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
     * @since 3.3.0
     *
     * @param string $post_type Post type.
-    * @param array  $args      Arguments used to register the post type.
+    * @param object $args      Arguments used to register the post type.
     */
    do_action( 'registered_post_type', $post_type, $args );

@@ -1365,7 +1466,7 @@ function register_post_type( $post_type, $args = array() ) {
 }
```